# What is the difference between struct node *head and struct node ** head?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to sort a linked list. I'm confused about when to use `struct node*head` and when to use `struct node **head`, the implementation can be done using both of them.

When should I use:

```
void sortedinsert(struct node **head)
```

and when should I use:

```
void sortedinsert(struct node *head)
```

Answer (score 15):

With this function signature:

```
void changeNode(struct node *head)
```

You have a pointer to the node, and so you can change that structure. You *can't* change what the variable head *points to*. Let's assume the following definition of `struct node`:

```
struct node
{
    int field1;
    struct node *next;
}
```

With the given function signature and `struct node`, consider the following operations can change the structure in the function:

```
void changeNode(struct node *head)
{
    head->field1 = 7;
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

C is pass-by-value: when we pass a variable to a function, the function gets a *copy*. This is why we pass a pointer to a `struct node`, so that we can change it, and have the effects of those changes outside the function. But we still get only a *copy* of the pointer itself. So the following operation isn't useful:

```
void changeNode(struct node *head)
{
    // we're only changing the copy here
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

The changes to `head` *won't* be reflected outside the function. In order to change what `head` points to, we must use an additional level of indirection:

```
void changeNode(struct node **head)
{
    // now we're changing head
    *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // alternately, we could also do this:
    *head = NULL;
}
```

Now the changes to `head` are reflected *outside* the function.

Answer (score 3):

`struct node **head` you are passing the address of the pointer of `head` there by making it possible to make it refer/point to a different memory area. With `struct node *head` you can't modify `head` to point anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

First one is a pointer to node which is a structure.

```
(struct node *) head;
```

defines `head` as a variable which can store the address of a `node`.

This allows to pass `node` by reference in a method.

Second one is a pointer to a pointer to node which is a structure.

```
(struct node **) head;
```

defines `head` as variable which can store address of another variable which has the address of a `node`.

This allows to pass a `node *` by reference in a method.

Answer (score 2):

if head has always to point at the head of the link list(a constant location) then use struct node* head
If you plan to change the location pointed by head use node **head

Comment: You could also change head by returning a new value from any function that could change it and assigning the result. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: When you are using:

```
void sortedinsert(struct node **head)
```

Inside the function you will **ACTUALLY be modifying** the `head` **pointer**, since most probably you will be using `*head` inside. The `sortedinsert` will most probably be called with the argument `&head`.

Case 2: When you are using:

```
void sortedinsert(struct node *head)
```

Inside the function you will be **modifying the copy** of the `head` **pointer**, since most probably you will be using `head` variable inside. The `sortedinsert` will most probably be called with the argument `head`.

Answer (score 0):

`node*` is a pointer to a node struct. `node**` is a pointer to a pointer to a node struct. Pointers to pointers are used in C when you want to modify a pointer by reference.

Say you want to do an operation on node B which could potentially replace node B with a different node. One way to do things is

`nodeA.next = foo(nodeA.next);`

The other option is to just do

`foo(&nodeA.next);`

And have foo implicitly replace the `nodeA.next` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, since the value of head may  change(It can point to some other nodes different from the current one) while it is being created,

You should be using,

```
void sortedinsert(struct node **head)
```

since your head may need to be modified.

And the below protoptye needs to be changed, it seems,

```
void sortedinsert(struct node *head)
```

since this does not allow you to modify head, It should be in this case (if you are using this),

```
struct node * sortedinsert(struct node *head)
```

which returns back  the updated head, which can be used in the caller of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Run or read this you can see it

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node{
    int one;
    int two;
    struct node * next;
    //char location[100];
};
void changeHead(struct node** head){

}
void sort(struct node* head){

}
int main(){
    struct node* head = (struct node*) (malloc (sizeof(struct node)));

    // now head pointing to a node stucture ( if you dereferance head you get teh first value)

    struct node* tmp = head;

    struct node** newHead = (struct node**) (malloc (sizeof(struct node*)));

    //New head points to a 'struct node*', which hold an addtess of another struct node

    head->one = 12;//*head->one =12; //head.one = 12 is wrong cos it is holding an address.
    // you can do it but it doesnt make sence since you dont know whats on address #12


    // now if you want head to point to old head which is on tmp at the moment
    *newHead = head;

    // now if you working with 2 linked list and you want to change the heads use below
    changeHead(newHead);

    // if you want to just sort its better and easy to use
    sort(head);

    //chack whats on head and newhead
    printf("double derefence newHead:%d\n",**newHead);
    printf("derefence newHead(its and address same ad address of head):%d\n",*newHead);
    printf("Head(its and address):%d\n",head);
    printf("derefence Head:%d\n",*head);//head->one works too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words use your `**head` when you want to change the location pointed by "head" else use `*head` where it doesn't allow to change the location.

Answer (score 0):

1. To make the change to the head which is pointer to the first
   node,you need to pass address of head ,i.e `(&head)` to call the
   function(therefore you have declared pointer to the pointer variable
   in the function `(struct node**head)` as it receives address of
   `head` which is nothing but pointer to the first node.
2. However if you know that head will remain fixed i.e you don't want
   head to point to some other node(like..no inserting a new node at
   the beginning) then you can only pass (head) to call the function
   and write `(*head)` in the function definition.